# Change order in a AppendOnlyHistory element

Tags: ordering, append-changes

I've got a list with a column that has the "Append Changes to Existing Text" option set. This is to enable users to add comments to the list item.

Using SharePoint Designer, I've replaced the default element on the custom edit page for the item with an AppendOnlyHistory element as shown below:

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="Comments" ControlMode="Display" />
```

This will render the comments like shown below.

[image]

Now, **the question** is, how do I specify the order in which the single comments are shown on the page? As you can see, the most recent comment is currently displayed on top. I'd like to have it rendered in the opposite direction so that the most recent comment is shown at the bottom.

We are using SharePoint 2013.